# how to set same value on java combobox in table cell editor on change event

Tags: swing, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have a table and have an combobox on each row in same column index. So the problem is I have 
I try to set same value on each row when I select an value on combobox. I read previously asked question about combobox on table cell editor and I tryed to implement answer to my code but I couldnt managed. I can see what I wished but My action listener sent many exceptions on behind. How to fix it?

the code for this table

```
        tblRadars= new JTable();
        tblRadars.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] {},
                new String[] {
                    "Radar", "Multicast IP", "Port", "Period", "Size", "Start", "Stop"
                }
            ) {
                /**
                 * 
                 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
        false, false, false, true, false, true, true};
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

  if (column == PERIOD_COLUMN_INDEX ){
  return ((JButton)getValueAt(row, START_COLUMN_INDEX)).isEnabled();
  }

return columnEditables[column];
     }
});

TableColumn periodColumn = tblRadars.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);

final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"1 min","30 min","1 hr" , "2 hr","4 hr","6 hr", "12 hr"});
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);

DefaultCellEditor ed=new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
periodColumn.setCellEditor(ed);
```

and my funny action listener is

```
ed.addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {

@Override
public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 String value=(String)tblRadars.getValueAt(tblRadars.getSelectedRow(),   PERIOD_COLUMN_INDEX);
 int row=tblRadars.getRowCount();
 for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
 tblRadars.setValueAt(value, i, PERIOD_COLUMN_INDEX);
 }
    }
```

From now thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really fool . Sometimes answer is really simple but we always see our problem big.

```
ActionListener comboBoxAction = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("period clicked.");
            int row=tblRadars.getSelectedRow();
                        int comboboxColumn=3 ;
            String selectedvalue=comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            for(int i=0;i<tblRadars.getRowCount();i++){

                tblRadars.setValueAt(selectedvalue, i, comboboxColumn);

            }



            ((DefaultTableModel)tblRadars.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    };
```

then add this action to combobox action listener.
:)

Comment: that's wrong: it's the responsibility of the _tableModel_ to keep itself consistent! Also, *never-ever* call any of the fireXX methods from outside of the model. Not quite sure to which combo you add the actionListener, but if it's the editor that's an invalid implementation: an editor _must not_ change the model directly.